# Angular - Is Output guaranteed when called in ngOnDestroy?

Tags: angular

The title says it all... is an output guaranteed to emit when being called during the OnDestroy lifecycle?

I know it works, as I've tested it but just need a guarantee or advice otherwise as why to avoid doing that.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused and don't understand the question. Could you provide a simple example to help explain what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

A definitive answer to this question probably should come from an Angular team member. However, it seems safe to assume that the event **will** be delivered. Remember that `onNgDestroy` is not about destroying the instance of the component; it's about the component ending its life cycle as a component within the view structure. As long as another component is "subscribing" to the `@Output` property of the component in question, the component instance should not be garbage collected, meaning that it, along with its emitter property, should be safe and continue to function until the event has been delivered.

Therefore, although this is not a "guarantee", it does seem safe to assume that the output **will** emit.

Comment: what if his `Output()` is based on DOM event in the component?

Comment: @deezg I don't understand your question. A DOM event in the component would be handled by a regular method doing the `emit`, so I don't see how that connects to the question relating to `ngOnDestroy`.

Comment: you could have dom element removed before/while ngOnDestroy still running and effectively he would be left with nothing to emit to `@Output`. As seen in discussion on link i have posted, `ngOnDestroy` docs are imprecise plus the question here smells like some potentially bad design.

Comment: I still don't understand. If the dom element is destroyed, it can no longer generate any events, so why would we be concerned if such events were passed along? The OP's question seems to be if an explicit `this.emitter.emit()` in `onNgDestroy` is guaranteed to be delivered to the listener, and as I said, and as the OP indicates his experiments confirm, I think it will be.

Comment: well, it highly depends on what triggers `emit`. if `emit` is in dom event handler and component gets destroyed at the same time as dom event happens do you still feel guaranteed `emit` delivery?

Comment: btw he did not ask about `emit` called from `ngOnDestroy` but during destroy cycle. although, even with calling explicitly from `ngOnDestroy` i would still be carefull for critical things that i need guarantee to be delivered.

Comment: /now i see in title he asks `in ngOnDestroy` and in text 'during'

Answer (score 0):

You should not count on it in a way you're thinking about it. Its not `ngOnDestroying` where the name would suggest that event is fired before any of destroying happens.
When event is fired, component destruction already started. For example, DOM is already removed.

You can see related discussion here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14252

[UPDATE]
You could maybe describe (or ask new question) what exactly are you trying to accomplish so we could see other options.